# Rscript not found in mac

Tags: php, r

If I execute an R program through macOS Terminal it works fine, but if I execute that program through PHP `exec()` I get an error which says "Rscript not found".

**submit.php:**

```
<?php
// print "hello";
$a = $_POST['a'];
$b = $_POST['b'];
// echo shell_exec("calc");
$output =  exec("Rscript /xampp/htdocs/demo/1.R ".$a." ".$b);
print $output
?>
```

**1.R:**

```
setwd("C:/xampp/htdocs/demo")
print("hello")
args=commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)
a = args[1]
b = args[2]
c = as.numeric(a)+as.numeric(b)
cat(c)
```

Comment: Need a little more to go on. What have you tried, what is the code you are using which apparently doesn't work, that sort of thing.

Comment: @abhiieor both are not working through php although in terminal they are working pretty good.

Comment: @Randall I have uploaded the code now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell the command interpreter where `Rscript` is located. In a normal login, you'd have a long `PATH` variable to search through, but when running from PHP you have a much more limited path. To figure out where the executable is located, type `which Rscript` from Terminal. Use the resulting path in your PHP script.

Also note that dumping raw user input into shell commands is a very bad idea. You should always use `escapeshellarg()` to make sure the input is sanitized. I would also suggest capturing the full output in the event that R outputs more than one line.

```
<?php
$a = escapeshellarg($_POST["a"]);
$b = escapeshellarg($_POST["b"]);
$r = "/xampp/htdocs/demo/1.R";
$lastline = exec("/usr/local/bin/Rscript $r $a $b", $output, $return);
// you could check the value of $return for non-zero values as well
// full output is returned as an array
echo implode("\n", $output);
```

Finally, you'll want to check your `setwd()` command in the R script. Might have some trouble with `C:` on a Mac! ;)